# Optimización código JS que muestra/oculta elementos

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un formulario de búsqueda y en función de un `select` muestro u oculto algunos filtros de búsqueda. El formulario funciona como se espera.

```
<?php

... código ...

/** texto ingresado por el usuario */
$que_buscar = null;
/** selección del usuario de dónde buscar (ver $donde_buscar) */
$buscar_en = null;
/** array con las secciones en las que se puede buscar */
$donde_buscar = array("clientes", "proveedores", "presupuestos", "trabajos", "fabricantes");
/** opciones del select que se componen desde $donde_buscar */
$donde_buscar_select = "\n\t\t\t\t\t<option value='0'>seleccione</option>\n";

... código ...

/* preparar las opciones del select buscar_en */
foreach ($donde_buscar as $key => $value) {
    $donde_buscar_select .= "\t\t\t\t\t<option value='$value'";
    if ($buscar_en == $value) { $donde_buscar_select .= " selected"; }
    $donde_buscar_select .= ">$value</option>\n";
}
$donde_buscar_select .= "\t\t\t\t";

... código ...
?>

        <form name="buscar" method="post" action="buscar.php">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="que_buscar">Buscar: </label>
                <input type="search" name="que_buscar" id="que_buscar" value="<?=$que_buscar;?>" required>
                <label for="buscar_en"> en </label>
                <select name="buscar_en" id="buscar_en"><?=$donde_buscar_select;?></select>
                <input type="submit" name="buscar" id="buscar" value="buscar">
            </fieldset>
            <!-- filtros de clientes -->
            <fieldset id="filtros_clientes" class="oculto">
                <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_direcciones" id="incluir_direcciones" value="incluir_direcciones"> incluir direcciones
                <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_telefonos" id="incluir_telefonos" value="incluir_telefonos"> incluir teléfonos
                <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_emails" id="incluir_emails" value="incluir_emails"> incluir emails
            </fieldset>
            <!-- filtros de proveedores -->
            <fieldset id="filtros_proveedores" class="oculto">
                <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_direcciones" id="incluir_direcciones" value="incluir_direcciones"> incluir direcciones (prov)
                <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_telefonos" id="incluir_telefonos" value="incluir_telefonos"> incluir teléfonos (prov)
                <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_emails" id="incluir_emails" value="incluir_emails"> incluir emails (prov)
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <script>
            const filtros_cliente = document.getElementById('filtros_clientes');
            const filtros_proveedor = document.getElementById('filtros_proveedores');
            const select_ctrl = document.getElementById('buscar_en');

            select_ctrl.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
                if (select_ctrl.value == "clientes") {
                    if (filtros_cliente.classList.contains('oculto')) {
                        filtros_cliente.classList.replace('oculto', 'mostrado');
                        filtros_proveedor.classList.replace('mostrado', 'oculto');
                    }
                }
                if (select_ctrl.value == "proveedores") {
                    if (filtros_proveedor.classList.contains('oculto')) {
                        filtros_cliente.classList.replace('mostrado', 'oculto');
                        filtros_proveedor.classList.replace('oculto', 'mostrado');
                    }
                }
                /* mas bloques if para cada opción del select */
            });
        </script>
<?php
... código ...
```

Mi consulta es: cómo podría hacer para no repetir los bloques `if` dentro del script? La intención es escribir un solo bloque `if` que pueda manejar cuantas opciones se muestren en el `select`.

Graceas!

**Ampliación solicitada:**

Cuando en el `select` se selecciona "clientes", muestra opciones para incluir/acotar los campos de dirección e email (entre otras cosas). Si luego se selecciona "proveedores" debe ocultar los filtros de cliente y mostrar los de proveedores, que van a ser otros distintos. Y así con fabricantes, presupuestos, etc. Ahora debo escribir un bloque `if` por cada opción seleccionada en donde se muestran los filtros correspondientes y se ocultan todos los demás.

Comment: Más óptimo sería utilizar [operador condicional ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: que harías si se selecciona presupuestos? puedes incluir eso en la pregunta? aun no me queda muy claro que pasa con las demás opciones... para poder ayudarte con una respuesta

Comment: @Pipe, edité la pregunta para añadir la aclaración solicitada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías entonces hacer algo así, asegurate que el `id` de cada uno de los filtros corresponda con los valores del select, es decir si el valor en el select es "clientes", que su filtro correspondiente se llame `filtros_clientes` y así con los demás, y podrías hacer esto:

```js
const select_ctrl = document.getElementById('buscar_en');
const filtros = document.querySelectorAll(".filtro");
select_ctrl.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

  filtros.forEach(f => {
    f.classList.add("oculto");
    f.classList.remove("mostrado");
  }); //Ocultas todos los filtros

  const filtroSeleccionado = document.getElementById('filtros_' + select_ctrl.value);
  filtroSeleccionado.classList.replace('oculto', 'mostrado'); //Solo muestras el seleccionado
});
```

```css
.oculto {
  display: none;
}

.mostrado {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form name="buscar" method="post" action="buscar.php">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="que_buscar">Buscar: </label>
    <input type="search" name="que_buscar" id="que_buscar" value="<?=$que_buscar;?>" required>
    <label for="buscar_en"> en </label>
    <select name="buscar_en" id="buscar_en">
      <option>clientes</option>
      <option>proveedores</option>
      <option>presupuestos</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="buscar" id="buscar" value="buscar">
  </fieldset>
  <!-- filtros de clientes -->
  <fieldset id="filtros_clientes" class="filtro mostrado">
    <label>filtros cliente</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_direcciones" id="incluir_direcciones" value="incluir_direcciones"> incluir direcciones
    <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_telefonos" id="incluir_telefonos" value="incluir_telefonos"> incluir teléfonos
    <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_emails" id="incluir_emails" value="incluir_emails"> incluir emails
  </fieldset>
  <!-- filtros de proveedores -->
  <fieldset id="filtros_proveedores" class="filtro oculto">
    <label>filtros proveedor</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_direcciones" id="incluir_direcciones" value="incluir_direcciones"> incluir direcciones (prov)
    <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_telefonos" id="incluir_telefonos" value="incluir_telefonos"> incluir teléfonos (prov)
    <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_emails" id="incluir_emails" value="incluir_emails"> incluir emails (prov)
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="filtros_presupuestos" class="filtro oculto">
    <label>filtros presupuestos</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_direcciones" id="incluir_direcciones" value="incluir_direcciones"> incluir direcciones (pres)

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Después de haber probado ambas contribuciones, elegí ésta respuesta ya que me parece que tiene un código mas legible. Gracias.

Comment: Quiero destacar una modificación. A la última línea del script la encerré en este `if`: `if (filtroSeleccionado != null) {` porque me daba un error/aviso y no puedo soportar que haya errores (aunque sean recuperables) o warnings.

Comment: Si te daba `filtroSeleccionado = null` es porque no existía la correlacion que dije al inicio... si tienes un elemento "clientes" debes tener un FieldSet con id = "filtro_clientes", porque si se llama por ejemplo "filtro_cliente" (sin la s) no lo va a encontrar y esa variable sería null. Porque se supone que cada opcion del select tiene su filtro correspondiente... entonces nunca debería ser null

Comment: Daba el error cuando volvía a la opción "Seleccione...". Como tiene un `id` diferente el objeto es `null`. Con el `if` se soluciona.

Comment: Cuando se recargaba la página después de enviar el `form`, los filtros no se mostraban aún estando seleccionada una opción (ver el `foreach` del post). Así que le añadí una mejora: después de asignar el evento al `select`, le añadí la siguiente línea: `select_ctrl.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`. De esta manera, cuando se recarga la pagina y se autocompletan los campos del `form`, también se muestran los filtros correspondientes sin estar teniendo que cambiar "donde buscar".

Answer (score 2):

Una opción sencillla sobre tu código es usar el valor del `select` como `id` del `fieldset` a mostrar/ocultar. Y usar una clase común ("mostrar-filtros" en el ejemplo) para ocultar todos y mostrar únicamente el seleccionado.

```js
            const select_ctrl = document.getElementById('buscar_en');
            let items_filtros = document.getElementsByClassName("mostrar-filtros"); 

            select_ctrl.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
                this_idseleccionado = document.getElementById(select_ctrl.value);
                
                      for(var index=0;index < items_filtros.length;index++){
                        items_filtros[index].classList.replace('mostrado', 'oculto');   }
                        this_idseleccionado.classList.replace('oculto', 'mostrado');
                
            });
```

```css
.oculto { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="buscar" method="post" action="buscar.php">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="que_buscar">Buscar: </label>
                <input type="search" name="que_buscar" id="que_buscar" value="<?=$que_buscar;?>" required>
                <label for="buscar_en"> en </label>
                <select name="buscar_en" id="buscar_en">
                <option value="">Elige una opción</option>
                  <option value="filtros_clientes">Clientes</option>
                  <option value="filtros_proveedores">Proveedores</option>
                  <option value="filtros_otros">Otros</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" name="buscar" id="buscar" value="buscar">
            </fieldset>
            <!-- filtros de clientes -->
            <fieldset id="filtros_clientes" class="mostrar-filtros oculto">
                <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_direcciones" id="incluir_direcciones" value="incluir_direcciones"> incluir direcciones
                <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_telefonos" id="incluir_telefonos" value="incluir_telefonos"> incluir teléfonos
                <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_emails" id="incluir_emails" value="incluir_emails"> incluir emails
            </fieldset>
            <!-- filtros de proveedores -->
            <fieldset id="filtros_proveedores" class="mostrar-filtros oculto">
                <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_direcciones" id="incluir_direcciones" value="incluir_direcciones"> incluir direcciones (prov)
                <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_telefonos" id="incluir_telefonos" value="incluir_telefonos"> incluir teléfonos (prov)
                <input type="checkbox" name="incluir_emails" id="incluir_emails" value="incluir_emails"> incluir emails (prov)
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="filtros_otros" class="mostrar-filtros oculto">
            otros
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```